# Vinyl Flooring Over Uneven Concrete Slabs

Tags: concrete, flooring, garage, vinyl-flooring, underlayment

Our attached garage was added many years after my house's 1959 construction by basically walling in a pre-existing carport. The floor, therefore, is made out of several concrete slabs and part of what used to be an outdoor walkway.

We live in Alaska and the slabs do not appear to have a frost footing (I think that it what its called), so they have warped, settled, and tilted over the years. In a couple spots, the edge of one slab is an inch or two higher than that of the adjoining slab and part of the floor is pretty heavily sloped.

Basically, its a mess.

The garage also houses our laundry room, a workshop, and a mudroom and we'd like these to be more finished, including adding vinyl wood-look flooring.

My question is: what is the best way to do this?

I am trying to decide if click-and-lock vinyl plank or vinyl sheeting will be easier and cheaper.  Also: can we level the concrete by adding underlayment or do we need to do a combination of grinding and self-leveling compound?  How important is it that the concrete be very level in order to add vinyl sheeting?

Comment: So is it an inch, or is it two? The difference is massive. Sounds to me like a new slab on a good base is your best bet. FYI, slabs don't usually have footings. The foundation walls do, but slabs rest mostly on the ground. Sometimes there are steps in the top of the foundation wall for support.

Comment: Also, the total level of the slabs is crucial. Have you checked that? Self-leveling underlayment can only be applied so thick, and the jog at the joint may not be the worst of your situation.

Comment: Short of replacing with a new slab (recommended) have you thought about maybe putting down plywood sheeting over "sleeper" joists, shimming them to make the whole "new" floor level? That would give you a nice flat clean level surface for your finish treatment.